# Return last inserted rows from table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm struggeling with this SQL query. The query is almost right, I just need the ticktimes to be the newest entries in the table. Right not the query is returning the oldest rows from each CurrencyID

```
+------------+------------+---------------------+------------+---------------+
| CurrencyID | MarketName | TickTime            | Last       | Volume        |
+------------+------------+---------------------+------------+---------------+
|          1 | BTC-LTC    | 2017-08-25 19:54:04 | 0.01169000 | 2502.10724529 |
|          2 | BTC-VTC    | 2017-08-25 19:54:05 | 0.00021742 | 2791.78612635 |
|          3 | BTC-DASH   | 2017-08-25 19:54:05 | 0.07104090 | 660.87899945  |
|          4 | BTC-XMR    | 2017-08-25 19:54:06 | 0.02189143 | 3682.28908088 |
|          5 | BTC-CANN   | 2017-08-25 19:54:06 | 0.00001145 | 1447.45006154 |
...
...
|         20 | BTC-BCC    | 2017-08-25 19:54:14 | 0.14220000 | 5196.84118604 |
+------------+------------+---------------------+------------+---------------+
```

My query I'm working with right now is looking like this. This is probably a simple problem, my sql is just rusty hehe

```
SELECT
    c.CurrencyID,
    c.MarketName,
    sub_table.TickTime,
    sub_table.Last,
    sub_table.Volume
FROM
    (SELECT
            CurrencyID,
            TickTime,
            Last,
            Volume,
            @rn:=CASE
                WHEN @var_CurrencyID = CurrencyID THEN @rn + 1
                ELSE 1
            END AS rn,
            @var_CurrencyID:=CurrencyID
    FROM
        (SELECT @var_CurrencyID:=NULL, @rn:=NULL) vars, Ticker
    WHERE
        CurrencyID IN (SELECT CurrencyID FROM Currency)
        ORDER BY CurrencyID, TickTime DESC) as sub_table
    INNER JOIN Currency c
        on c.CurrencyID=sub_table.CurrencyID
WHERE
    rn <= 1
ORDER BY CurrencyID , TickTime DESC;
```

The output is fetched from these two tables:

```
Currency
+------------+--------------+------------------+------------+----------+--------------+------------+
| CurrencyID | CurrencyName | CurrencyNameLong | MarketName | IsActive | MinTradeSize | TxFee      |
+------------+--------------+------------------+------------+----------+--------------+------------+

Ticker
+----------+------------+---------------------+------------+------------+------------+---------------+
| TickerID | CurrencyID | TickTime            | Bid        | Ask        | Last       | Volume        |
+----------+------------+---------------------+------------+------------+------------+---------------+
```

**EDIT:**
To make things a little bit clearer: I want the TickTime to be the newest records inserted in the table. This is an exemple of how I want the output to be like:

(rn <= 1 will be changed to list more records...)

```
+------------+------------+---------------------+------------+---------------+
| CurrencyID | MarketName | TickTime            | Last       | Volume        |
+------------+------------+---------------------+------------+---------------+
|          1 | BTC-LTC    | 2017-08-28 16:40:00 | 0.01169000 | 2499.55344592 |
|          1 | BTC-LTC    | 2017-08-28 17:40:04 | 0.01169000 | 2502.10724529 |
|          2 | BTC-VTC    | 2017-08-28 16:40:01 | 0.00021742 | 2791.78613576 |
|          2 | BTC-VTC    | 2017-08-28 17:40:05 | 0.00021742 | 2791.78612635 |
|          3 | BTC-DASH   | 2017-08-28 16:40:02 | 0.07104060 | 660.88002045  |
|          3 | BTC-DASH   | 2017-08-28 17:40:05 | 0.07104090 | 660.87899945  |
|          4 | BTC-XMR    | 2017-08-28 16:40:02 | 0.02178855 | 3681.62291540 |
|          4 | BTC-XMR    | 2017-08-28 17:40:06 | 0.02189143 | 3682.28908088 |
|          5 | BTC-CANN   | 2017-08-28 16:40:03 | 0.00001154 | 1449.06053986 |
|          5 | BTC-CANN   | 2017-08-28 17:40:06 | 0.00001145 | 1447.45006154 |
...
...
|         20 | BTC-BCC    | 2017-08-28 16:40:10 | 0.14265409 | 5196.39621496 |
|         20 | BTC-BCC    | 2017-08-28 17:40:14 | 0.14220000 | 5196.84118604 |
+------------+------------+---------------------+------------+---------------+
```

Comment: try to change this Part -> ORDER BY  TickTime DESC, CurrencyID ;

Comment: Unfortunately that only changes the order in which CurrencyID are returned. Because the returned TickTime values are still the same, I believe

Comment: So you want the TickTime to be the same value across all records in the result set? The maximum value found in the Ticker table?

Comment: I updated the question to make things a little clearer. Hope this helps!

Comment: What is your expected O/P?